# Crontab does not run all scripts / jobs

Tags: php, unix, curl, cron

I have this crontab

```
company@shell:~$ crontab -l

MAILTO="my@email.com"
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.company.com/crontest.php > null 2>null
2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.company.com/crontest-2.php > null 2>null
```

The first script works perfect, but the second one is not being run.

What is wrong here?

Comment: your first one is running every second (******) - what do you think that means ?

Comment: every min, every hour,every day, every month

Comment: @Up_One I think it is every minute. cron supports every minute minimum

Comment: Every minute, just for testing right now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for second one, with the url within double quotes:

```
2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl "http://www.company.com/crontest-2.php" > null 2>null
```

Your script terminated because of `-`. Check your cron log.